# Gradle: Task does not execute another task based on the configuration it uses

Tags: gradle

I've got a very simple multiproject build like below:

**module1**, which generates a public API jar and exposes it through "**publicAPI**" configuration:

```
configurations {
    publicAPI
}

task generatePublicAPI(type: Jar) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    baseName 'public-api'
    from sourceSets.main.output
}

artifacts {
    publicAPI generatePublicAPI
}
```

**module2**, which uses the public API jar (by referencing 'publicAPI' configuration defined in module1) to generate a application jar:

```
configurations {
    generateApplication
}

dependencies {
    generateApplication project(path: ':module1', configuration: 'publicAPI')
}

task jarApp(type: Jar) {
    baseName 'app'
    from configurations.generateApplication.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
}
```

Now, when I execute 'gradle :module2:jarApp" task, I got the **following error**:

> Cannot expand ZIP
>   '/home/picasso/Documents/GradlePlayground/module1/build/libs/public-api.jar'
>   as it does not exist

and I can see that gradle was **not trying to execute 'generatePublicAPI'** of module1.

**However**, if I make "jarApp" task depends on "generatePublicAPI" task explicitly,

```
task jarApp(dependsOn: 'module1:generatePublicAPI', type: Jar) {...}
```

then everything's fine.

**BUT**, wouldn't this approach against one of the purpose of using dependency configuration so that I don't have to worry about the details of how module1 is built, e.g. which task generates the jar and what artifacts it produces?

I thought gradle is able to work out the tasks it needs to execute by following along the "route" of the referenced dependency configuration.

Am I missing something here so that "generatePublicAPI" task can be executed automatically without have to declare "dependsOn" explicitly for "createApp" task?

Comment: Basically as far as I see `module2` depends on `module1`. Maybe adding `evaluationDependsOn(':module1')` in build.gradle for `module2` will help? And this is not the case that gradle always can resolve dependencies between projects/modules. Sometimes it needs help ;). That's why the methods are defined.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! However, adding "evaluationDependsOn(':modules1')" does not work. I got the same error message.

Comment: Is the project hosted online? Github?

Comment: Oh, no, it's on my local machine. But I guess I'll push it to github when I got home so that you can try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question on Gradleware's forum and got the answer from one of the core developer, here's the [link](http://gsfn.us/t/4oodw).

Basically, the issue is that `collect` method returns a new collection but gradle has no way to know that this new collection was generated from the configuration, therefore it couldn't infer which task to execute.

The solution is instead of declaring a dependency on a task, declare a dependency on the actual configuration instead like the following:

```
task jarApp(dependsOn: configurations.generateApplication, type: Jar)
```